# Retry when no response from website

Tags: javascript, recursion, phantomjs, casperjs

I use the recursive function below, in order to reopen website if `httpstatus != 200`:

```
retryOpen = function(){

    this.thenOpen("http://www.mywebsite.com", function(response){
        utils.dump(response.status);
        var httpstatus = response.status; 
        if(httpstatus != 200){
            this.echo("FAILED GET WEBSITE, RETRY");
            this.then(retryOpen);
        } else{
            var thisnow = hello[variable];
            this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
                $('select#the_id').val(valueOptionSelect);
                $('select#the_id').trigger('change');
            },thisnow);
        }
    });        
}
```

The problem is that sometimes the `retryOpen` function does not even go as far as to callback `function(response){}`. Then, my script freezes.

I wonder how one could change the function to be able to recursively try to open website again if there is no response from website (not even some error code as 404 or something)? In other words, how to rewrite the `retryOpen` function so it reruns when the function does not reach callback after a certain amount of time?

Comment: Have you checked that `response` is actually an object shortly before it freezes? `function(response){ this.echo("not null: " + !!response) ...`

Comment: this.echo("not null: " + !!response) prints `true` and utils.dump(response) prints `200`.

Comment: Even when it freezes?

Comment: @ArtjomB. Have not tried to echo it before. Tried just now... Any suggestions?:)

Comment: Looks like a case of `this` having different context within your function than what you expect it to be.

Comment: @charlietfl Hm ok, please explain or write an answer:)

Comment: Check that `this` is what you expect it to be

Comment: @charlietfl Not if `retryOpen` is called as a step like `casper.then(retryOpen)` or `casper.start(url, retryOpen).run()`

Comment: @ArtjomB. So `this` does have corrent context? I mean it works everytime besides when the script freezes...

Comment: @ArtjomB. How would you solve it?

Comment: I would try to figure out if it always freezes in the same operation or if there are differences. Perhaps there is something special the page is doing. Enable debug output and register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Ok mate, thanks. I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. Please note this is untested code, but should get you on the correct path

```
retryOpen = function(maxretry){
    var count = 0;
    function makeCall(url)
    {
         this.thenOpen(url, function(response){
            utils.dump(response.status);        
        }); 
    }

    function openIt(){
        makeCall.call(this,"http://www.mywebsite.com");
        this.waitFor(function check() {
            var res = this.status(false);
            return res.currentHTTPStatus === 200;
        }, function then() {
             var thisnow = hello[variable];
                this.evaluate(function(valueOptionSelect){
                    $('select#the_id').val(valueOptionSelect);
                    $('select#the_id').trigger('change');
                },thisnow);
        }, function timeout() { // step to execute if check has failed
            if(count < maxretry)
            {
                openIt.call(this);
            }
            count++
        }, 
        1000 //wait 1 sec
        );
    }
 openIt();
}
```

Comment: What does waitFor do actually in this case ?:)

Comment: It will hold the call chain until the check function returns true, or the timeout occurs. From there the check function is validating the current status of the last request made for a status 200. For more information see [CasperJs Docs](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor)

Comment: Ok thanks! I will try your example as soon I can and accept if it works:)

Comment: I forgot the open call at bottom try with that in there

Comment: Ok, should I call `retryOpen` like this: `retryOpen.call(this, 'www.mywebsite.com)'`?

Comment: Depending on where u call it from, and that context. retryOpen(5). "this" should be the Casperjs reference

Comment: I call it in a function like `this.then(retryOpen)`, so should I call it like this: `retryOpen(5)` now?

Comment: how do you mean? Chat?:)

Comment: var casper = this;
this.then(function(){retryOpen.call(casper, 5);}));

Comment: Hm still does not work. Are you sure it is corrent approach? I can show code in chat